# How to stop VSCode from auto-skipping Node Internals while debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to understand how certain node internal modules work, and wish to deliberately step into the node core while debugging my js files. I've tried setting the `skipFiles` property in Launch.json to an empty array `[""]` but VSCode somehow auto-attaches `"<node_internals>/**"` to it

Comment: A hack I found was to set the `skipFiles` property to `["<node_internals>/**/*.cc"]`

Comment: this didn't work for, but it was worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
"skipFiles": [
    "!<node_internals>/**"
],
```

Comment: this didn't work for me for vscode 1.77.1

Comment: Did you copy it exactly as I wrote it? Notice the exclamation mark.

Comment: yes, i did - thanks for the question. i wanted to update my response and got sidetracked. the issue i ran into was that it is necessary to restart the vscode window in order to have the option take effect. i've gotten used to vscode not requiring restarts - i'm spoiled i guess.